# How can I use telnet to set my modem/router to bridge mode?

Tags: networking, router, modem, bridge

I have an ActionTec T2200H modem/wireless router combo that I use solely as a ADSL2+ modem. From the web interface the bridge mode is hidden but by enabling telnet I find options for bridging, just I don't know enough to set it up through this CLI.
Here is a list of available commands once logged into the modem:

```
> ?
help
logout
exit
quit
reboot
adsl
xdslctl
xdslctl0
xdslctl1
xtm
brctl
cat
loglevel
logdest
virtualserver
ddns
df
dumpcfg
dumpmdm
meminfo
psp
kill
dumpsysinfo
dnsproxy
syslog
echo
ifconfig
ping
ps
pwd
sntp
sysinfo
tftp
wlctl
arp
defaultgateway
dhcpserver
dns
lan
lanhosts
passwd
ppp
restoredefault
route
save
swversion
uptime
cfgupdate
swupdate
exitOnIdle
wan
gpv
mcpctl
```

Here is the command list of `brctl`:

```
Usage: brctl [commands]
commands:
        addbr           <bridge>                add bridge
        delbr           <bridge>                delete bridge
        addif           <bridge> <device>       add interface to bridge
        delif           <bridge> <device>       delete interface from bridge
        setageing       <bridge> <time>         set ageing time
        setbridgeprio   <bridge> <prio>         set bridge priority
        setfd           <bridge> <time>         set bridge forward delay
        sethello        <bridge> <time>         set hello time
        setmaxage       <bridge> <time>         set max message age
        setpathcost     <bridge> <port> <cost>  set path cost
        setportprio     <bridge> <port> <prio>  set port priority
        enableportsnooping      <bridge> <value>        0-disable 1-standard 2-blocking
        enableproxymode <bridge> <value>        To enable 1 or disable 0
        show                                    show a list of bridges
        showmacs        <bridge>                show a list of mac addrs
        addmacs         <bridge> <port> <mac>           add mac addresses to the bridge table
        delmacs         <bridge> <port> <mac>           remove mac addresses from the bridge table
        showstp         <bridge>                show bridge stp info
        stp             <bridge> {on|off}       turn stp on/off
        mldenableportsnooping   <bridge> <value>        0-disable 1-standard 2-blocking
        mldenableproxymode      <bridge> <value>        To enable 1 or disable 0
        enableigmpratelimit     <bridge> <value>        0-disable, 1..500-packet rate
```

Here is the command list of wan:

```
> wan
Usage:
       wan add interface <atm|ptm|eth>
       wan add service <interfacename> --protocol <bridge|ipoe|pppoe|ipoa|pppoa>
       wan delete interface atm <port.vpi.vci>
       wan delete interface ptm <port> --priority <normal|high|both>
       wan delete interface eth <ethx>
       wan delete service L3IfName
       wan show interface
       wan show [<port.vpi.vci>]
       wan --help <bridge|pppoe|pppoa|ipoe|ipoa>
```

And the command list of wan bridge:

```
> wan --help bridge
Usage:
       wan add service <L2interfacename> --protocol bridge
       [--service <servicename>]
       wan delete interface atm <port.vpi.vci>
       wan delete interface ptm <port> --priority <normal|high|both>
       wan delete interface eth <ethx>
       wan delete service L3IfName
       wan show interface
       wan show [<port.vpi.vci>]
       wan --help <bridge|pppoe|pppoa|ipoe|ipoa>
```

Does anyone have enough information to point me in the right direction to get this set up?

Comment: “How can I use telnet to set my modem/router to bridge mode?” – In general? You cannot. The firmware has to support it. Even being able to access a shell doesn’t change that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This relies on the bridge being the bridge you’re thinking of. Based on the output of the command this is a “bridge” tool for making vlans, not for a DSL to 802.3 bridge. Any of these settings would likely be in the web interface, but if not then you may have to call your Internet Provider and ask for one that functions as solely a modem.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I was hoping I had stumbled on some hidden settings to do what I was needing but apparently I'm not that lucky. I'll just have to ask TDS like you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

While the accepted answer is correct in most cases...

Yes, all Actiontec modems and routers have the same functions for telnet/ssh that they have for the web gui, but sometimes have extras from the console. The Verizon FiOS actiontec routers (mi424wr) do infact have some hidden features in the CLI. As you have found, they use busy-box. The bridge control (brctl) command is indeed what you would need to do this from the command prompt. I am assuming your ISP is Telus, as that's what came up in my searches for this model number.

You will have to investigate the interface names to get this going.
normally you would use a command like this:

> brctl addif br0 eth0 eth1

Where br0 is the bridge name, and eth0 & eth1 are the interfaces you wish to bridge. I would recommend backing up your configuration settings before you start messing around in the CLI.
(just in-case you need to do a factory reset)

I found instructions for this router to put it into bridge mode from the web GUI. (Telus firmware)

1. In the address bar of your browser type 'http://x.x.x.x' where the x's are the IP number of your modem, and then press Enter
2. The Gateway’s Home screen will appear. Enter your user name and password and then click the Wireless Setup icon located in the top row of icons.
   (disable the wireless if you are using another WiFi router.)
3. Click on Advance Setup on the right side.
4. Click on Port Bridging.
5. The Port1 Bridge screen should appear (see below) - click Enable and then click Apply.
   [image: bridge]

Let me know if Telus isn't your ISP, the GUI instructions would change dramatically on another ISP's firmware.